# Vaadin 8 Combobox howto selected fist item

Tags: combobox, vaadin, vaadin8

I tried the following:

```java
 machineComboBox.setEmptySelectionAllowed(false);
 machineComboBox.focus();
 this.addComponent(machineComboBox);
```

I read:

[Cannot set focus on combobox inside a grid](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/16843620/cannot-set-focus-on-combobox-inside-grid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly you are trying to achieve? If you simply want to select the first item, then this should work:

```java
machineComboBox.setSelectedItem(yourItems.get(0));
```

Example is taken from here : [Selection Components](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/components/components-selection.html#components.selection)

`focus()` doesn't select anything, only focuses (outlines) the component.

Comment: yes works:  machineComboBox.setSelectedItem(itemsCollect.get(0))